# MATLAB - Can't see methods or properties of a COM object

Tags: matlab, com, amibroker

I am trying to use MATLAB R2016a to access Amibroker via Amibrokers COM interface.
I used the following code to create a COM server in MATLAB:
AB = actxserver('Broker.Application')

When I use get(AB), Matlab returns 'struct with empty field'. There is nothing in the Inspector when I double click on the AB object.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do the functions [`properties`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) or [`methods`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html) work on `AB`?

Comment: If I write JavaScript codes and run it with wscript.exe, they all work. It is a bit strange. I prefer MATLAB because I am familiar with it.